# p4 sync Perforce command line to sync multiple trees to one changelist by entering the changelist only once

Tags: command-line, perforce, synchronization, alias

How can I sync 2 completely separate trees at a given changelist by entering the changelist only once, e.g. giving the same result as

```
p4 sync //tree1/a/b/c/...@1234 //tree2/d/e/...@1234
```

which works, but requires entering 1234 twice?

This gives "syntax error near unexpected token `('":

```
p4 sync (//tree1/a/b/c/... //tree2/d/e/...)@1234
```

This syncs //tree1/a/b/c/... to head instead:

```
p4 sync //tree1/a/b/c/... //tree2/d/e/...@1234
```

The main reason is that I want to make a shell alias but the 1234 part is user-entered, so it must be entered only once. I know I can use a shell script or function but for various reasons, I must use an alias.

Comment: I don’t understand why you can’t use the user-entered variable twice in the alias.

Comment: @Timwi because at least in bash, "there is no mechanism for using arguments in the replacement text. If arguments are needed, a shell function should be used". Reasons for requiring an alias would be interesting to know though.

Comment: @romkyns: Thanks. It's actually meant to be a macro in AutoHotkey which expands, say, "p4sync" to the string and then typing space, backspace and the changelist number to complete it. As AHK literally types it out, I can then use arrow keys to modify it for edge cases. I thought that's too long-winded to explain, so described it as an alias. By the way, how did you get such a nice symmetrical identicon?

Comment: Have you tried the syntax "p4 sync {//tree1/a/b/c/...,//tree2/d/e/...}@1234"?  I think it expands to what you want.

Comment: @CalebHuitt-cjhuitt: Excellent — that works! Thank you very much. If you'd like some brownie points, please submit it as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, the (bash, at least) shell syntax of

```
p4 sync {//tree1/a/b/c/...,//tree2/d/e/...}@1234
```

should work.  For more explanation, see the [brace expansion section](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion) of the bash reference.